# Why orderby="date" does not support manually changed posts?

Tags: posts, theme-development, themes, order

I have this in my theme style:

```
<?php $args = array('order' => 'DESC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'nopaging' => false, 'posts_per_page' => '15', 'category__in' => array(21));
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
       $query->the_post();
?>
       <article>
         <!--  Here Last News, This comment added by sirsaleh:. -->
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12  ">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 no-padding">
         <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                 the_post_thumbnail('newstree-thumbnail', array('class' => 'col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 no-padding '));
          }
         ?>
         </div>
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9 ">
         <h4><?php if (function_exists('the_subtitle')) the_subtitle(); ?></h4>
         <h3><a title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"
         href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
         <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
         </div>
         <hr class="hratna">
         </div>
         </article>
                   <?php
      }
   }else {
```

}

it sorts descending my category post by initial publish date of posts,but when I change date of publish in post edit (for example to now) like below
[image]

it not changes, and my post position remain fix!
How can I make my theme order of showing posts responsive to change of post's date manually.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your CODE works just fine, just tested. So it's most likely a cache related issue. Clear all cache from any cache plugin, query cache etc. Clear your browser cache and reload. If nothing happens, then make a small change to a post & see if it appears in the list. This will confirm cache related issues.

Comment: @Fayaz Not worked again! when I change the date of post even the order in all posts in admin panel does not change! Very strange!! looks like sth. is wrong.

Comment: @Fayaz The problem solved! You guess what? a plugin installed that changing my post queries automatically! Previous system admin didn't mention me that! thanks fayaz :) the Idea of checking plugins was good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `post_date`:

```
'orderby' => 'post_date'
```

check if you have `sticky posts` too, sticky posts will always on top of your result.

Comment: There is also no `sticky posts`! I tried `post_date` But it not works! sorry :(